'eas build -p android' gives error AAPT: error: resource color/splashscreen_background (aka com.xxxxx.xxxxx:color/splashscreen_background) not found
I am using react native and try to create an apk file with "eas build -p android --profile preview --clear-cache"
On https://expo.dev/ I see the following gradle build error.
`> Task :app:processReleaseResources
FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
Android resource linking failed
ERROR: /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/splashscreen.xml:3: AAPT: error: resource color/splashscreen_background (aka com.xxxxx.xxxxx:color/splashscreen_background) not found.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 6m 49s`

My aps.json file looks like:
{   "expo": {     "name": "Xxxxx",     "slug": "Xxxxx",     "owner": "xxxxx-xxxxx",     "privacy": "public",     "platforms": [       "ios",       "android"     ],     "version": "0.0.1",     "orientation": "portrait",     "icon": "./assets/icon.png",     "updates": {       "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0     },     "assetBundlePatterns": [       "**/*"     ],     "ios": {       "supportsTablet": true,       "bundleIdentifier": "com.xxxxx.xxxxx",       "buildNumber": "1.0.0",       "splash": {         "image": "./assets/splash.png",         "resizeMode": "contain",         "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"       }     },     "android": {       "package": "com.xxxxx.xxxxx",       "versionCode": 1,       "adaptiveIcon": {         "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",         "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"       },       "splash": {         "image": "./assets/splash.png",         "resizeMode": "contain",         "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"       }     },     "web": {       "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"     },     "extra": {       "eas": {         "projectId": "e93c6d02-02d5-4238-8fe4-b03fdac9784b"       }     }   } }
package.json file:
{   "name": "xxxxx",   "version": "0.2.4",   "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",   "scripts": {     "start": "expo start",     "tunnel": "expo start --tunnel",     "android": "expo start --android",     "ios": "expo start --ios",     "web": "expo start --web",     "test": "jest --verbose",     "format": "prettier --write .",     "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",     "commit": "git add --all && git commit -m 'update' && git push",     "storybook-generate": "sb-rn-get-stories --config-path .ondevice",     "storybook-watch": "sb-rn-watcher --config-path .ondevice",     "storybook:get": "sb-rn-get-stories --config-path .ondevice && STORYBOOK_ENABLED='true' expo start",     "storybook:ios": "sb-rn-get-stories --config-path .ondevice && STORYBOOK_ENABLED='true' expo start --ios",     "storybook:android": "sb-rn-get-stories --config-path .ondevice && STORYBOOK_ENABLED='true' expo start --android"   },   "dependencies": {     "@babel/preset-env": "^7.24.5",     "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.21.0",     "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.6.1",     "@react-native-community/slider": "4.4.2",     "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.0",     "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.0.0",     "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",     "axios": "^1.6.8",     "expo": "~50.0.6",     "expo-constants": "~15.4.6",     "expo-status-bar": "~1.11.1",     "jest": "^29.2.1",     "jest-expo": "~50.0.4",     "react": "18.2.0",     "react-dom": "18.2.0",     "react-native": "0.73.6",     "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.8.2",     "react-native-screens": "~3.29.0",     "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",     "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",     "regenerator-runtime": "^0.14.1"   },   "devDependencies": {     "@babel/core": "^7.24.5",     "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.24.3",     "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.16",     "@storybook/addon-controls": "^6.5.16",     "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.5.16",     "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.16",     "@storybook/addon-ondevice-actions": "^6.5.1",     "@storybook/addon-ondevice-backgrounds": "^6.5.1",     "@storybook/addon-ondevice-controls": "^6.5.1",     "@storybook/addon-ondevice-notes": "^6.5.1",     "@storybook/addon-react-native-web": "^0.0.19",     "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.5.14",     "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.5.14",     "@storybook/react": "^6.5.16",     "@storybook/react-native": "^6.5.7",     "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.1.2",     "@types/react": "~18.2.45",     "atomic-bomb": "^5.0.0",     "babel-loader": "^8.2.3",     "babel-plugin-react-docgen-typescript": "^1.5.1",     "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.18.10",     "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.77.0",     "typescript": "^5.3.0",     "webpack": "^5.91.0"   },   "resolutions": {     "react-native-svg": "13.4.0"   },   "private": true,   "jest": {     "preset": "jest-expo",     "transformIgnorePatterns": [       "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)"     ]   },   "babel": {     "presets": [       [         "@babel/preset-env",         {           "loose": true,           "shippedProposals": true         }       ]     ]   } }
My eas.json file:
{   "cli": {     "version": ">= 6.0.0"   },   "build": {     "development": {       "developmentClient": true,       "distribution": "internal"     },     "preview": {       "android": {         "buildType": "apk"       },       "distribution": "internal"     },     "production": {}   },   "submit": {     "production": {}   } }
metro.config.js:
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('expo/metro-config')
const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname)
defaultConfig.resolver.resolverMainFields = [
'sbmodern',
...defaultConfig.resolver.resolverMainFields
]
defaultConfig.transformer.getTransformOptions = async () => ({
transform: {
experimentalImportSupport: false,
inlineRequires: false
}
})
defaultConfig.watchFolders = [...defaultConfig.watchFolders, './.ondevice']
module.exports = defaultConfig
I could not found a solution and I have no idea how to fix this.
I tried to remove folder node-modules and did a npm install but did not help.

remove the splash property content from ios and android and place it in on top in the app.json file.
after that run "expo prebuild"
after that run "expo run:android"
test it!

Sorry for mine five cents but an error message say that color "splashscreen_background" doesn't define in resources. Just find a file values/colors.xml and add missed value.
Below an example of file content
<resources>
  <color name="colorPrimary">#023c69</color>
  <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffffff</color>
  <color name="splashscreen_background">#ffffff</color>
</resources>


I had the same problem and I was able to add myself in the app.config splash file... my app.config code:
export default { expo: { android: { package: "com.xxxxxxxx", versionCode: 3, name: "af", displayName: "af", icon: "./assets/af.png", targetSdkVersion: 34, adaptiveIcon: { foregroundImage: "./assets/af.png", backgroundColor: "#ffffff" } }, splash: { image: "./assets/splash.png", // Make sure this image exists and the path is correct resizeMode: "contain", // It can be "contain" or "cover" backgroundColor: " #ffffff" // Background color of the splash }, extra: { eas: { projectId: "xxxxxxxxx" } } } };
Remember to link app.config to app.json:
"extra": { "eas": { "projectId": "xxxxxxxxxxx" }, "config": "./app.config.js" }

